HTML how to change element outside scope in innerHTML
My school's online judge (a website for code problem-solving and testing) supports users to change their signature. It uses the JavaScript code below:
signature = "Student Signature"; // Random Signature
elem = document.createElement("div");
elem.innerHTML = signature;

Where the signature can be changed by the student.
The thing is, we like to have rotating signatures so we wrote <i class="loading icon"> Signature in the signature to make it rotate and even overlap other content (for fun). However, the teacher found out and decided to change the parent division's style to <div style="overflow: hidden"> so it won't overlap. Here's the example HTML code generated as an example after the change:
<div style="position:relative;overflow:hidden"> Signature </div>

Question: Is there any way to change the signature such that it can delete the style of the division outside the scope, or alternatives such that the icon will overflow?
P.S. must be at most 80 chars. (sry miscounted the chars)
My Try: I tried to write my signature as </div><div><i class="loading icon"> my_signature (the website will automatically add </i></div> at the end) but it didn't work. It was because (I think) the website expected me to put stuff in the scope, not end it.

Java is not the same as javascript. Also it is not clear what you want to achieve.

Off topic: just out of interest, what is an "online judge"?

the created element is not attached anywhere in the dom; the overflow hidden is nowhere going to prevent what you described you were supposed to do; the code you tried to inject in the innerHTML is not valid html anyway and it's not clear how it should "hack" the container; talking about compiler doesn't make any sense; in short this question is a mess

How much "code" can the student add?   Do they just add the string Student Signature somewhere?   Or is the snipper you've provided what the user edits?   elem.innerHTML = means the page/site is open to all sorts of attacks / hacks.

@DiegoD I would guess that the user has an input box to enter Student Signature then the partial-code that OP has provided is on the page, along with other code/html on that page.  OP only has access to change the signature value, not the code (well, not as they see it yet...).   As a guess.

@fdomn-m yes it makes sense as you described the scenario.. I was playing hard

</div><div> won't work as you're not changing the HTML source - only the html inside the div that's created, which gets converted to DOM nodes, not injected as HTML.

What is the CSS for loading and icon? Where is the 40-character limit verified?

one trick could be using position:absolute as long as that string won't be sanitized like "<div style='position:absolute;'>Student Signature</div>" .. but it will be positioned relative to the closest container having position: relative

Note that your attempt in the final paragraph of your question has 48 characters. So what is this 40 character limit about?

Why no response to these comments?

You can escape the normal rendering flow with position:fixed. The signature element will then be positioned relative to the viewport and not be clipped.
See it work here:


let elem, signature;

signature = "<i style='position:fixed' class='loading icon'>Student Signature";
elem = document.createElement("div");
elem.innerHTML = signature;

document.querySelector("div").appendChild(elem);
#signature { width: 200px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid; }
.loading { animation: spinner 1.5s linear infinite; }
@keyframes spinner { to { transform: rotate(360deg); } }
Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
<p>
Your signature: 
<div id="signature" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;"></div>



Disclaimer: I didn't understand the 40-character limit, and this wasn't clarified when I asked.

Doesn't work... See the code snippet generated: https://note.ms/voak, you'll see that the "overflow: hidden" argument in the parent division makes the text completely blank and does not appear.

Sorry, but you just updated your question showing that the wrapping div has a style position: relative. This is essential information was not mentioned in your original question. It is a bit blunt to then just come back with "Doesn't work". I will however look at your modified question.

I updated my answer having seen your updated question.

So sorry to not have shown all the information, but adding z-order:-1 still doesn't make the text appear...

Still see note.ms/voak

Can you show the surrounding html so the issue is reproducible?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
